# C# Entity Framework : sort on 3 columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a C# application that is using Entity Framework. I have a table which looks like this:

```
ID    FILENO        Col1   Col2    Col3
---------------------------------------
1     19873          42    129     145
2     19873          42    129      41 
3     19873          42    130      18
4     19873          43    158     168
```

I need to sort the table by `Col1`, then by `Col2` and then by `Col3` and select the "lowest" record. In this case, I should select record 2.  I have tried this code:

```
var model = db.Cxxxx.Where(x => x.FILENO == '19873').FirstOrDefault();
```

But that just gets a record, not necessarily the "lowest" record.  I know there is a `.Min<>()` option but I do not know how it works.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you read up on [`OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.orderby?view=net-7.0) and [`ThenBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.thenby?view=net-7.0). Also, [`Min`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.min?view=net-7.0) is fully documented.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var model = db.Cxxxx.Where(x => x.FILENO == "19873")
            .OrderBy(x => x.Col1)
            .ThenBy(x => x.Col2)
            .ThenBy(x => x.Col3)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

This of course assumes that "lowest record" means the top record resulting from the three levels of sorting.

At the request of another member, I will add a bit of an explanation although it seems pretty straight forward to me:

The `Where` method is filtering your set by the records with the File No you are looking for.
The `OrderBy` method performs the first sort based on `Col1`.
The `ThenBy` performs a second sort on the previous result based on `Col2`.
The next `ThenBy` performs a third sort on the previous result based on `Col3`.
Selecting the first result should then yield the desired record.

Please note that `model` will be `null` if no record matching the File No is found.

Comment: I would suggest some explanation of your code would help make your answer more useful to someone who is apparently unfamiliar with LINQ.

Comment: @NetMage The methods are named in a way that is pretty self-explanatory. You can literally read this out loud and "get it".

Comment: @NetMage - I "get it".

Comment: I don't think your explanation for `ThenBy` is at all accurate. Firstly, since this is EF, it all gets translated to SQL, so `OrderBy`+`ThenBy` just sets the columns used in the SQL `ORDER BY` clause. Secondly, even in LINQ to objects, `OrderBy` doesn't perform a sort and `ThenBy` perform a sort. Instead, `OrderBy` orders by its value and `ThenBy` sub-orders any duplicates and only one sort is performed when the `IEnumerable` is actually enumerated.

Comment: Because programming is about accuracy and correctness. Teaching things that are incorrect, or being imprecise, creates mental models of the system that result in questions on StackOverflow based on these fundamental misunderstandings. For example, it is important to know that only one sort occurs.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I assume you have set the DBContext properly.

To do this we can use two ways

```
var lowestRecord = context.MyEntities
    .Where(e => e.FILENO == 19873) // Filter by FILENO if needed
    .OrderBy(e => e.Col1)
    .ThenBy(e => e.Col2)
    .ThenBy(e => e.Col3)
    .FirstOrDefault();

if (lowestRecord != null)
{
    // Use lowestRecord
}
else
{
    // No records found
}
```

Above code using FirstOrDefault, and the below Code using Min

```
var lowestRecord = context.MyEntities
    .Where(e => e.FILENO == 19873) // Filter by FILENO if needed
    .OrderBy(e => e.Col1)
    .ThenBy(e => e.Col2)
    .ThenBy(e => e.Col3)
    .Min();
```

Comment: Why do you think the `Min` version will do anything useful?

Comment: The Min method will retrieve the entity with the minimum value of all columns (Col1, Col2, and Col3) among all records that satisfy the Where condition.

I have used this kind of similar queries in my projects.

Comment: 1. The `OrderBy.ThenBy.ThenBy` has no effect on the result of `Min`. 2. Why do you think `Min` will ignore the `ID` and `FILENO` columns when comparing the rows? 3. `Min` used on the entire entity will not be translated to SQL as SQL has no equivalent and EF doesn't have the code to create a full row sort + first translation 4. Even if you used `AsEnumerable` to do client side processing, the entity class for the SQL row will not implement `IComparable` by default, as an ordering for entities rarely makes sense and can't be assumed.